# Malzilla Tutorial #4 - how to get it working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the basic work flow of using [Malzilla](http://malzilla.sourceforge.net/) , and therefore doing the tutorials. But already in the [first one](http://malzilla.sourceforge.net/tutorial04/index.html), where you actually get to do something I am lost as it doesn't work for me at all, even though I follow it step by step.

In the first paragraph where you have to concatenate the string and then translate it using the `MiscDecoders->DecodeUCS2`, I am getting not printable chars as a solution, after concatenating and using the decoder.

In the second paragraph where you are told to run the script after adding the function-call at the bottom of the script, the Decoder tells me that he cannot handle the `arguments.callee.toString()` method and therefor wont run the script.

How outdated are those tutorials and how can I get them to work?

Comment: Sounds like a question for [su] since it relates to application/tool functionality, as opposed to security.

Comment: well the tool is most certainly IT-Security related

Comment: Just because the tool is "IT Security related", doesn't make all questions about that tool "IT Security questions".  For example, BackTrack 5 (and all that it includes) is definitely an "IT Security related" tool because it's a pentesting suite.  Questions about defending your systems from the attacks that BT5 facilitates are definitely "IT Security questions".  But when I've got a problem *using* that tool, I generally go to [su], [unix.se], or [ubuntu.se].

Comment: well anyhow I think that leaving this question on IT-Security would supply a higher possibility of being answered, as a programmer who might know something about an IDE but less of general usage of programs would rather answer a Question about eclipse on StackOverflow than superuser